# Difference equation with initial condition in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I have this difference equation `y[n] + a1 y[n − 1] = x[n]` with initial condition `y(-1) = 0` and i have implemented this as following but I don't understand how to implement the initial condition `y(-1) = 0` I'm not allowed to use the built in function in Matlab like `filtic` or `filter`

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
x = zeros(1,20);
x(1) = 1;
a1 = -0.8;

N = length(x); % Length of input signal
y = zeros(size(x)); % Allocate space for outut

y(1) = -a1*x(1); % First sample, assuming x(0) = 0
%y(1) = 0; % First sample, assuming x(0) = 0

for n=2:N % Remaining samples
    y(n) = -a1*y(n-1) + x(n);
end

nn=-1:18;
stem(nn,x,'b');
hold on
stem(nn,y,'r');
box on
axis([-1 20 -1.5 1.5]);
xlabel('n');
ylabel('x(n) och y(n)');
legend('x(n)','y(n)');
```

Comment: You'll probably want to create an [array function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), or something similar to this.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `x(1)=-1` because of your initial condition?

Comment: The line you have commented out with `y(1) = 0` solves your question - why have you commented this out? You don't update `x(n)` anywhere so it's all zeros but for the first element, this seems like it's probably not the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Wolfie it was just there that i don't understand , when i run with that line the output signal is just 0. I have tested the code with the built in command `filter` the plot of the code differ with the one using `filter` so some where i do something incorrectly which cause that they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general case of recurrence equation provides a relationship between a given output and previous output (as well as current and previous inputs). Since the previous output would also depend on earlier outputs, you have to cut the chain somewhere. That's what the initial condition allows you to do by fixing the values at some initial point in time. For example for `n=0`, the given recurrence equation would yield

```
y[0] + a1 y[0 − 1] = x[0]
```

or equivalently

```
y[0] = x[0] - a1 y[-1]
```

The initial condition `y[-1] = 0` then allows you to remove the previous output dependency and to simplify the expression to

```
y[0] = x[0] - a1 * 0
     = x[0]
```

Converting to Matlab's usual 1-based array indexing would give you the following:

```
y(1) = x(1); % First sample, assuming y(0) = 0

for n=2:N % Remaining samples
    y(n) = -a1*y(n-1) + x(n);
end
```